# Wait for condition in given timeout

Tags: python, wait

I was wondering if there was a sufficient way or a module to wait for a condition(function that returns bool),  in given timeout?  Example

```
def wait_for_condition(condition,  timeout, interval) :
    # implementation 
    # return True if the condition met in given timeout, else return False
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would simply roll your own, this seems simple enough :

```
def wait_until(condition, interval=0.1, timeout=1, *args):
  start = time.time()
  while not condition(*args) and time.time() - start < timeout:
    time.sleep(interval)
```

Comment: This should be "not condition(*args)". Otherwise it'll wait for a condition to become false, which I suspect is the opposite of what you want.

Comment: It will keep waiting while the condition is false so you do want it the not.

Answer (score 0):

I love the prior answer by @alpha1554, but wanted to return whether there was a timeout or not. Also, since one could call it with a lambda I didn't feel the need to take ***args** and pass them to the predicate. Here is my variation:

```
def wait_for(pred, poll_sec=5, timeout_sec=600):
    start = time.time()
    while not (ok := pred()) and (time.time() - start < timeout_sec):
        time.sleep(poll_sec)
    return ok
```

Calling it with a predicate that takes args and has non-bool return value:

```
wait_for(lambda: get_some_status(some_arg) != "IN_PROGRESS")
```